# SSO for Fiddler

Tags: single-sign-on, fiddler, kerberos

I am using a proxy with SSO enabled. When I try to run fiddler,my browser challenges me for authentication though SSO is enabled. When fiddler is turned off,the SSO works fine. So,how can I let my fiddler use SSO credentials used by my proxy for authentication.

Answer (score 1):

In the Rules menu enable the "Automatically Authenticate" option. That will make Fiddler authenticate with your domain user credentials.